# What does this “bagged” mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw on the 2016 November's NEW SCIENTIST a sentence:

> The capsule, containing hydrogen isotopes, sits in a spherical target chamber (pictured, top right). Its science-fiction looks **bagged** it the role of the warp core of the USS Enterprise in Star Trek: Into Darkness.

In this sentence, what does "bag" mean? Or is there any misspelling?

Comment: The metaphor is rather transparent and self-explanatory, even if you've not seen this usage of the word before. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bag#Verb As to misspelling, the very first word is misspelled, yes. The rest are fine.

Comment: I am afraid it makes no sense to me, even if I correct "It's" to "Its" and "it" to "in". Maybe it's because I am not familiar with the referenced movie. Why don't you provide more context?

Comment: @RegDwigнt I have voted to reopen the question and look forward to reading your answer.

Comment: Note that "bagged it" is an idiom, similar to "hit the nail on the head" or "struck the right note".  In other words, it got the representation just right.  The quote appears to be missing a word, though.

Comment: The only possible way I see to parse the (corrected) sentence is this: *Its science-fiction [appearance earned the capsule] the role of the warp core of the USS Enterprise in Star Trek: Into Darkness.* They seem to be saying that the film production used the actual capsule because of its looks..

Comment: @michael.hor257k Right. So if we are looking at exactly one possible way to parse this, and that way makes perfect sense to boot, then what exactly is left of the question.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I wish to remain polite, so I'll just politely suggest that your attitude is inappropriate. It wasn't until I saw the actual picture that it occurred to me that *looks* is a noun here, not a verb. I am sure I wasn't the only one thrown off by this. Your summary dismissal of the issue as trivial is ... well, as I said, inappropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real problem with the given sentence is not the meaning of ***bagged***, but the role of ***looks***. The natural tendency is to read it as a verb - but then the rest of the sentence doesn't make sense, especially the immediately following word ***bagged***.

Once you realize that ***looks*** here is a noun, and replace it with a synonym such as ***appearance***, the sentence acquires a meaning - and so does the word ***bagged***, which in this context means [***gained, acquired***](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bag) or ***earned***:

> Its science-fiction [appearance] [earned] it the role of the warp core
>   of the USS Enterprise in Star Trek: Into Darkness.

Comment: In British English, if we attain something we have been striving for, we can say "it's in the bag", as well as that we have bagged it.

Comment: Thank you very much. At last I understood what the sentence has to say.

Comment: I think that perhaps when a hunter caught a small bird or animal it might be put in a bag to be carried home.

Comment: In British game hunting, a person's achievements each day are called his or her "bag". "I had a good day - my bag was ten pheasant, five grouse, and two hare." Perhaps confusingly, plural game animals are referred to using the singular noun.

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article that you could reference in your answer for more information about this type of problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence

Answer (score 1):

'bagged' simply means 'got'. Another meaning (similar) would be to 'capture'.
For example: I bagged two birds during my hunt.

Here are some examples from dictionary.com:

> verb (used with object), bagged, bag·ging.
>   to cause to swell or bulge; distend: The wind bagged the curtain.
>   to put into a bag.
>   Informal. to kill or catch, as in hunting: I bagged my first deer when I was a teenager.